# How to ignore null parameter in Spring JPQL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

I have an API created like this. It works when you supply both parameters, but I want it to work when either parameter is null. Is there a way?

```
@Query("Select u from User u where u.agency = :agency and " +
            "(u.firstName like %:firstName%)")
    public List<User> multiParam(Agency agency, String firstName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@Query("Select u from User u where (:agency is null or u.agency = :agency) and " +
        "(:firstName is null or u.firstName like %:firstName%)")
public List<User> multiParam(Agency agency, String firstName);
```

For more reference, check the [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-null-parameters).

Comment: This works but can you explain how this works? Why would adding is Null check in front make it ignore null?

Comment: IS NULL will check it is null or not. 
For instance, if you send agency as null then (:agency is null or u.agency=:agency) will be evaluated as true, thereby not affecting the whole where clause.